# Samsung dryer starts spinning after a few seconds with accompanying noise

Tags: dryer, noise

When I turn on the dryer, I first hear a whirring noise for a few seconds, with the drum not moving, then a "bang" or a "bump" and the drum starts spinning. Clothes are still drying.

Do you think something is going to fail soon? I can order the part(s) in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most dryers have a drive belt that runs from the drum to the motor to a tension pulley. It your belt is worn, at start up, the motor would spin and then grab the belt and spin the drum. Check the belt. you can usually access it by removing the back panel of the dryer. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, it does have a drive belt, and I've had to replace it before, so thanks, will order a replacement.